# inferSchema using spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") is inferring double for a date type column

Tags: excel, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on PySpark (**Python 3.6 and Spark 2.1.1**) and trying to fetch data from an excel file using **spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")**, but it is inferring double for a date type column.

Example:

Input -

```
 df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").\
     option("location", "D:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\TmpData\\Input.xlsm").\
     option("spark.read.simpleMode","true"). \
     option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").\
     option("addColorColumns", "false").\ 
     option("useHeader", "true").\  option("inferSchema", "true").\
     load("com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

Result:

```
Name | Age | Gender | DateOfApplication
________________________________________
X    | 12  |   F    |  5/20/2015

Y    | 15  |   F    |  5/28/2015

Z    | 14  |   F    |  5/29/2015
```

**Printing Schema** -

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Age: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DateOfApplication: double (nullable = true)
```

**Doing .show** -

```
df.show()

Name | Age | Gender | DateOfApplication
________________________________________
X    | 12.0  |   F    |   42144.0

Y    | 15.0  |   F    |   16836.0

Z    | 14.0  |   F    |   42152.0
```

While the reading of the data-set the dates or any other numeric value is being converted to double (special problem with date is that it totally changes the value which is hard to be reverted back to original dates.

Can I please be helped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author of the plugin here :)

Inferring column types is [done in the plugin itself](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/crealytics/spark/excel/InferSchema.scala).
That code was [taken from spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/InferSchema.scala). As you can see from the code, only String, Numeric, Boolean and Blank cell types are currently inferred.

The best option would be to create a PR which properly infers date columns by using [the corresponding DateUtil API](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isCellDateFormatted(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell)).

The second-best option would be to specify the schema manually similar to how @addmeaning described. Note that I've just released version 0.9.0 which [makes some required parameters optional](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/commit/446e747cad85468635e1fe68056595ec1d7765c3) and [changes the way the path to the file needs to be specified](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/commit/6da6955190dbfb21cc7f991de7286c813cb7413f).

```
yourSchema = StructType()
                     .add("Name", StringType(), True)
                     .add("Age", DoubleType(), True)
                     .add("Gender", StringType(), True)
                     .add("DateOfApplication", DateType(), True)

df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
         schema(yourSchema).
         option("useHeader", "true").\
         load("D:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\TmpData\\Input.xlsm")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how the plugin will infer DateType from the column in excel file with this specific format ('5/29/2015')?

Comment: Hey Nightscape,

So you're saying instead of using com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.8.4, I can use the newly released 0.9 plugin and avoid using the inferSchema=true and it would work? I'd try and let you know. Otherwise, I'll try the DateUtil to convert the double back to the Date type. Shall keep you posted. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @addmeaning AFAIK, Excel internally encodes dates as doubles. The String "5/29/2015" is just a user-visible representation of the internal encoding.
The plugin currently won't infer this as a date column because the corresponding functionality hasn't been added yet.

Comment: @AakashBasu The newly released 0.9 version has inferSchema=false as default, so you don't need to specify this option if you don't want it to infer the schema automatically.
A manually specified schema will have precedence over the inferred one anyway, so you should be able to do something like in the example above.

Comment: I commented with the solution what I finally opted for, and also found a new problem in the 0.9.0 release, please see into it -

https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/pull/13

Comment: @AakashBasu Just update spark-excel to 0.9.0 version without schema inferring. Starting with 0.9.0, ExcelRelation uses POI DataFormatter to represent strings instead of just passing string field as in 0.8.3 version (unfortunately, there's no releases younger then 0.8.5 in git):

    case _: StringType => datum

This solve the issue and you can see dates in dataframe the same way as excel represents them

Answer (score 0):

Spark can't infer Date type. You can specify schema manually and read DateOfApplication as a string and then convert it to date. Read your df this way:

```
    yourSchema = StructType()
                         .add("Name", StringType(), True)
                         .add("Age", DoubleType(), True)
                         .add("Gender", StringType(), True)
                         .add("DateOfApplication", StringType(), True)

    df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
             schema(yourSchema).
             option("location", "D:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\TmpData\\Input.xlsm").\
             option("spark.read.simpleMode","true"). \
             option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").\
             option("addColorColumns", "false").\ 
             option("useHeader", "true").\  //no infer schema
             load("com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, but, I've a very wide data-set, as in some 30+ columns, do I have manually specify schema and connect it with the input set? No other easier solution to it?

Comment: I only want 10 columns out of the data set, can I directly create the schema for only those 10 columns and select them directly while reading the file?

Comment: I get this error if I avoid inferSchema option while reading dataset (seems it is a mandate) -

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.load.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter "inferSchema" is missing in options.

Can you pls help?

Comment: you can read file as rdd and pick only needed columns and then convert rdd to DF

Comment: Are you aware of any JAR which helps to read an Excel (.xlsm) file for an RDD?

How do you think I should proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying schema might fix this issue.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField("Name", StringType(), False),
                    StructField("Age", DoubleType(), False),
                    StructField("Gender", StringType(), False),
                    StructField("DateOfApplication", DateType(), True)])
```

> Add schema to spark.read.

```
df_excel= spark.read.
                   format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
                   schema(schema).
                   option("useHeader", "true").
                   option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false").
                   option("inferSchema", "false"). 
                   option("addColorColumns", "false").
                   load(file_path)

display(df_excel)
```