# How to load excel sheet in spark using Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

code to create dataframe by excel sheet.

```
df = spark.read.load("examples/src/main/resources/people.xls", format="xls")
```

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic since it has specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following package worked for me : `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.11.1` .

It's a maven repository so due process is required to use it as a dependency.

I tried it using pyspark shell:

Starting the shell with `--packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.11.1`

Followed by reading the file in the following manner -

```
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("useHeader","true").load(filePath)
```

In addition you might come across a problem with data types while inferring schema .This problem is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713699/inferschema-using-spark-read-formatcom-crealytics-spark-excel-is-inferring-d).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spark-excel](https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice) or [hadoopoffice](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) libs for this.

```
# spark-excel example. 
pyspark --master local[2] --packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.13.1    
>>> spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("header", "true").load("/tmp/example.xlsx").show()

+-------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|Table 1| _c1| _c2| _c3| _c4| _c5| _c6|
+-------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|     X1|  X2|null|null|null|null|null|
|     11|  12|null|null|null|null|null|
|   null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
...
```